# angular- how to reduce DOMContentLoaded time of angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface, lazy-loading

i am practicing angular and created an app where i add only 3 components. My app took 26 secs to load, so to reduce this time i used Lazy load concept in my app, but still this thing is not working. I still got 26 secs to load my app after implementing lazy load concept.

Note: I am testing my app on 3g network.

Refer screenshot for better understanding
[image]

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';


const routes:Routes=[
  {path:"pipes",
  loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pipe-module/pipe-mod.module').then(m => m.PipeModModule)},
  {path:"products",
  loadChildren: () => import('src/app/product-module/product-mod.module').then(m => m.ProductModModule)},
  {path:"users",
  loadChildren: () => import('src/app/user-module/user-mod.module').then(m => m.UserModModule)},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
  
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.1",AA
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Every thing is working fine, but i want to reduce this DOMContentLoaded time of my app as low as possible

Comment: you should propably mention that you are testing with 3G network connection :).
the most of the load time is from the  ```vendor.js```  chunk which includes your dependencies. Can you post your installed packages from your ```package.json```?

Comment: i added both things

Comment: i believe you are testing your app on the `ng serve` server. that means that the app is not minified. if you want better result at least use --prod option `ng serve --prod` to see how your app behaves on production build